# Codeigniter insert left join

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I do a left join to insert database codeigniter?

```
$this->load->database();
$data = array('id_co_karta' => '', 'nazwa_co_karta' => $_POST['name']);
$this->db->join('kategoria_karta', 'kategoria_karta.id_kategoria_karta = karta.kategoria_karta');
$this->db->insert('co_karta', $data);
```

Comment: What do you mean by left join to insert ?

Comment: $data =     $this->db->join('kategoria_karta', 'kategoria_karta.id_kategoria_karta = karta.kategoria_karta', 'left');
$this->db->insert('co_karta', $data);

Answer (score 0):

insert data

table 1 key name

```
id | name | img |
```

table 2

```
id | name |
```

key name.

As you do insert into 2 tables